# Try block exiting without doing anything in the debugger

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms application with Azure mobile services. Currently, I am doing something like this:-

App.cs

```
public const string applicationURL = @"myUrl";
public const string applicationKey = @"myKey";
public static MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL, applicationKey);
```

MainPage.cs

```
public MainViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return this.BindingContext as MainViewModel ; }
    set { this.BindingContext = value; }
}

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.ViewModel = new MainViewModel (App.client);}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public MainViewModel(MobileServiceClient client) : this()
{
    this.client = client;
    LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
}

public ObservableCollection<MainModel> mainDetails{ get; set; }


private Command loadItemsCommand;
/// <summary>
/// Command to load/refresh items
/// </summary>
public Command LoadItemsCommand
{
    get { return loadItemsCommand ?? (loadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand())); }
}

private async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
{
    if (IsLoading)
        return;

    IsLoading = true;

    try
    {
        var details= await client.GetTable<MainModel>().ToListAsync();

        MainDetails.Clear();
        foreach (var mDetails in details)
        {
            MainDetails.Add(mDetails);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var page = new ContentPage();
        var result = page.DisplayAlert("Error", "Error loading data. Please check connectivity and try again.", "OK", null);
    }

                IsLoading = false;
}
```

When my debugger reaches the Try block in the MainviewModel.cs, it suddenly exits without doings anything. It does not even go to the Catch block. Is there anything I am doing wrong? How can I find out what is causing the issue?

Comment: What kind of application is this? WP8?

Comment: @JohnSaunders It is a Xamarin forms application

Answer (score 2):

> When my debugger reaches the Try block in the MainviewModel.cs, it suddenly exits without doings anything.

That's because of the nature of async methods, they yield control back to the calling method once hitting the first `await`. This is an expected behavior. Simply set a breakpoint on the line after your await, and you'll see it reaching it once the asynchronous operation is complete.